# input type file Isset returning false even when set

Tags: php, file, isset

I am uploading a picture, but `isset()` returns `false` even when I clearly picked a file. Here is my code.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"    action="addroom.php">
<p>Upload pictures:</p>
<p>Bed:</p>
<input type="file" name="image1"/>
<p>Comfort room</p>
<input type="file" name="image2"/>
<p>Living room:</p>
<input type="file" name="image3"/>              
<input type="submit" id="add" name="add" value="Add Room Category"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['image1']))
    $file1=$_FILES['image1']['name'];
else
    echo "image not selected";
```

Comment: Post your `<form>` tag?

Comment: <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="addroom.php">

Comment: PROTIP: To format code, paste it in and then highlight it and press Ctrl+k or click the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploaded files are stored in `$_FILES`.  `$_POST['image1']` does not exist because that is a file, not a text (or other) field.

You want to use either:

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
```

or

```
if(isset($_FILES['image1']))
```

Comment: JANGO! I was just going to say that!

Comment: thank you so much! hope i could improve on this subject

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_FILES["image1"]["name"])){...}
```